# NavigationLink programatic dismiss is no longer working on iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As probably most of us I updated my iPhone to iOS 15. Sadly I have noticed that the dismissal of a view via the `Binding` of the `NavigationLink` is no longer working as it was on iOS 14. It works with the first link but not with the second or later.

iOS 14.5:

[image]

iOS 15.0:

[image]

I created a small project that recreates the issue:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    enum NextView: Hashable {
        case view1
    }

    @State private var nextView: NextView?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Next", action: { nextView = .view1 })
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .background(
                NavigationLink(
                    tag: .view1,
                    selection: $nextView,
                    destination: {
                        View1 { dismissReason in
                            nextView = nil
                        }
                    },
                    label: EmptyView.init
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    enum NextView: Hashable {
        case view2
    }

    enum DismissReason {
        case back
    }

    let onDismiss: (DismissReason) -> Void

    @State private var nextView: NextView?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Back", action: { onDismiss(.back) })
            Button("Next", action: { nextView = .view2 })
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .background(
            NavigationLink(
                tag: .view2,
                selection: $nextView,
                destination: {
                    View2 { dismissReason in
                        nextView = nil
                    }
                },
                label: EmptyView.init
            )
        )
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    enum NextView: Hashable {
        case text
    }

    enum DismissReason {
        case back
    }

    let onDismiss: (DismissReason) -> Void

    @State private var nextView: NextView?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Back", action: { onDismiss(.back) })
            Button("Next", action: { nextView = .text })
        }
        .background(Color.green)
        .background(
            NavigationLink(
                tag: .text,
                selection: $nextView,
                destination: { Text("Destination") },
                label: EmptyView.init
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it run on Simulator on the same device as where you see the error? I ran your code in Playgrounds with Xcode 13.0 (13A233) (this is RC), and it works as expected.

Comment: I ran it on my iPhone 11 and on the iPhone 13 simulator both with 15.0. Both show the same issue where the back button in the center on the first screen (yellow) works but not on the second screen (green).

Comment: I found a possible workaround, please see my update.

Comment: I just ran into this issue too. Very frustrating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce your error and frankly, there seems to be something wrong which is not in your code. Below is a screen shot which replaces 1000 words of explanation.

Here, we are on a breakpoint after the "back" button in View2 has been tapped. The `nextView` state variable has been set correctly to `nil`.

When we proceed with running, the View2 does not disappear, though.

Basically, what's wrong (from my understanding) is, that the condition for rendering the destination is *FALSE* (which is correct), but nonetheless, View2 will be drawn - respectively *not removed*.

Note, that the body of View2 runs, even when the condition is false.

Why this is the case, and whether this is "legal" or a bug in SwiftUI needs to be investigated elsewhere. I would suggest to create a bug report and file it to Apple.

[image]

**Update:**

I found a workaround and a possible cause of this behaviour. The NavigationLink will be handled differently for iPad and iPhone. If the navigationViewStyle is `column`, on iPad we always see the first view and the second view on the stack. We cannot pop "back" the second view and there is also no "back" button. The third view and any subsequent view pushed on the stack have a "back" button and can be popped of course.

The behaviour in the given code seems like as if it is using a "column" view.

So, the workaround to fix this, is for rendering on iPhone I would suggest to explicitly set `stack` as the navigationViewStyle:

```
NavigationView {
    ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

Otherwise, for iPad, it depends how you want to show the navigation stack view.

So, the default NavigationLinkStyle, which is `automatic` does show this issue when running on iPhone. I would consider this a bug and report to Apple is justified.

The style `columns` (which is available only in iOS 15) is not applicable for the iPhone.

Comment: Great thank you Yes on iPhone the default should behave like `.stack` does and it kind of is the wrong way round. I would expect the second view to work and the first not, as that is the NavigationLink that has a back button on the iPad.

Comment: Thank you. Would have loved to have gotten a heads up from Apple on this fundamental breaking change.